# What is the right syntax for launching an executable in Appveyor?

Tags: appveyor

I'm trying to start the Azure Storage Emulator in an AppVeyor instance but I can't find the right syntax. I've tried this:

```
- ps: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" start
```

and this:

```
- ps: & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" start
```

and this:

```
- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" start
```

All fail with various unhelpful YAML parsing errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- cmd: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" start'
```

or simple:

```
- '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" start'
```

or with PowerShell:

```
- ps: '& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" start'
```

Easiest way to avoid YAML parsing errors is to do initial configuration in UI and then press `Export YAML`. GitHub search for `appveyor.yml <something>` often brings useful results too.